# Manually define only part of copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I'm wondering if there is a way to implement copy constructors and assignment operators such that only a small modification is needed when these are redefined for a class.

For example, consider a class as such:

```
class Foo {
private:
    int* mInt_ptr;
    /* many other member variables
       of different types that aren't
       pointers */
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo&);
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&);
    ~Foo();
};
```

Now, in order to deal with the pointer `mInt_ptr` I would need to handle it appropriately in the copy constructor and assignment operator. However, the rest of the member variables are safe to do a shallow copy of. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Once a class becomes large it may become tedious and unwieldy to explicitly write out the operations to copy the non-pointer member variables, so I'm wondering if there is a way to write, say, a copy constructor such as:

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& tocopy)
{
    mInt_ptr = new int(*tocopy.mInt_ptr);
    /* Do shallow copy here somehow? */
}
```

rather than the explicit form of:

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& tocopy)
{
    mInt_ptr = new int(*tocopy.mInt_ptr);
    mVar1 = tocopy.mVar1;
    mVar2 = tocopy.mVar2;
    ...
    ...
    mVarN = tocopy.mVarN;
}
```

Comment: Why not wrap mInt_ptr in a class of its own?

Comment: Could you memcopy it?  Or is this not allowed for some reason?  I have this feeling that it would only be safe to do this for non-polymorphic classes (i.e. those with no subclasses or superclasses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, don't use raw pointers, for exactly the reason that you're now fighting with. Instead, use a suitable smart pointer, and use copy-swap assignment:

```
class Foo
{
     int a;
     Zip z;
     std::string name;
     value_ptr<Bar> p;

public:
     Foo(Foo const &) = default;

     Foo & operator=(Foo rhs)
     {
         rhs.swap(*this);
         return *this;
     }

     void swap(Foo & rhs)
     {
         using std::swap;
         swap(a, rhs.a);
         swap(z, rhs.z);
         swap(name, rhs.name);
         swap(p, rhs.p);
     }
};

namespace std { template <> void swap<Foo>(Foo & a, Foo & b) { a.swap(b); } }
```

The `value_ptr` could be a [full-blown implementation](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/a3365a24524e/include/wheels/smart_ptr/value_ptr.h%2B%2B), or something simple such as this:

```
template <typename T>    // suitable for small children,
class value_ptr          // but not polymorphic base classes.
{
    T * ptr;

public:
    constexpr value_ptr() : ptr(nullptr) { }
    value_ptr(T * p) noexcept : ptr(p) { }
    value_ptr(value_ptr const & rhs) : ptr(::new T(*rhs.ptr)) { }
    ~value_ptr() { delete ptr; }
    value_ptr & operator=(value_ptr rhs) { rhs.swap(*this); return *this; }
    void swap(value_ptr & rhs) { std::swap(ptr, rhs.ptr); }

    T & operator*() { return *ptr; }
    T * operator->() { return ptr; }
};
```

Comment: Great, thanks for that. I haven't looked into smart pointers very much so far but I'll make sure I become more familiar with them.

I haven't gone through it carefully, but would you mind briefly describing the extra functionality of the pointer implementation you've linked to over the one you've shown here?

Comment: @Wheels2050: The pointer that RMF provides in his Wheels library can deal with polymorphic classes by looking for a `clone()` member function. Note how I say `new T(*rhs.ptr)`, which assumes that the *dynamic* type of `*ptr` is `T`. That may not always be the case. In fact, there's been an entire proposal for the standard to include such a smart pointer which never made it because nobody can agree on how it should really look.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I must admit I still don't fully understand how the pointed to type could be different, but I'll think about it. I'm still very much coming to grips with much of C++.

Comment: @Wheels2050: Imagine I have a `value_ptr<Base> p(new Derived)`. That would break immediately! (For fun, imagine that `Base` is abstract, too.)

Comment: Ah, now is that because a pointer to a derived class is compatible with the base class? Therefor there would be no compile-time complaints about that call, but it would cause a run-time error?

Comment: @Wheels2050: Yes. Well, you wouldn't end up copying the correct object. Basically, *because there is no virtual copy constructor in C++*, if that makes sense.

Comment: I think so. Thanks a lot for your help - I've learned a lot, but I also see a whole lot of stuff I need to check out!

Comment: Your operator=() definitions lack return.

Answer (score 2):

How about you wrap all the shallow-copy bits in a small helper struct and use the default copy behaviour there.

```
class Foo {
private:
    int* mInt_ptr;
    struct helper_t
    /* many other member variables
       of different types that aren't
       pointers */
    } mHelper;
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo&);
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&);
    ~Foo();
};

Foo::Foo(const Foo& tocopy)
{
    mInt_ptr = new int(*tocopy.mInt_ptr);
    mHelper = tocopy.mHelper;
}
```

Using better primitives, as Kerrek suggested, seems like better design though. This is just another possibility.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's a simple thing I hadn't considered before. I'll likely use smart pointers but thanks for pointing this out too.

Comment: Yea, it's actually a useful trick if you want to use default constructors for all or most members and want something else to happen in your copy-ctor, e.g., syncing caches or registering with some framework. Just in this case you probably just want better default copy behavior of your members.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless if you use raw pointers or smart pointers the Kerrek's solution is right in the sense that you should make a copy constructor, destructor and swap and implement assignment using those:

```
class Foo 
{
private:
    int* mInt_ptr;
    // many other member variables
    // of different types
public:
    Foo()
        : mInt_ptr(NULL)
        // initialize all other members
    {}
    Foo(const Foo& that)
        : mInt_ptr(new int(*that.mInt_ptr) )
        // copy-construct all other members
    {}
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& that)
    {
        // you may check if(this == &that) here
        Foo(that).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        delete mInt_ptr;
        // and release other resources
    }
    void swap(Foo& that)
    {
        std::swap(mInt_ptr, that.mInt_ptr);
        // swap all members
    }
};
```

The members are inline here just to keep it compact, usually it is not advisable to burden class definition with inline member definitions.

Comment: Thanks, I just came across the copy-swap idea for the first time when I was researching this question. I need to look into it in more detail.